# Extraer registros usando el protocolo Modbus RTU

Tags: c#, ip, tcp, modbus

soy nuevo en el uso del protocolo Modbus. Tengo un dispositivo de convertidor de medios (MOXA), estoy probando la conexión con los programas Modbus Poll y Modscan para corroborar que se esté transmitiendo datos. Tengo estas configuraciones en el dispositivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando el protocolo TCP y el puerto 502

[image: Usando el protocolo TCP y el puert 502]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De acuerdo a esas configuraciones, configuro en Modscan los siguientes campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Configuro el Device Id = 240 y selecciono "03. HOLDING REGISTER" para la lectura de los datos, más sin embargo obtengo los siguientes mensajes "uninitialized" y posteriormente "Received Invalid Response TO MODBUS Query" ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? ¿Alguna idea?

De igual manera usando "Modbus Poll" obtengo los siguientes mensajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

espero que ya hayas logrado resolver tu problema, de no ser el caso debes revisar la configuraion del servidor remoto en los programas que estas empleando: modscan y el modbus poll.

en ambos programas tienes configurado el servidor remoto con la siguiente direccion: 10.10.10.254. cuando dberia ser 10.10.10.100, tal como la tienes configurada en el convertidor de medios(MOXA).

debes cambiar dicho valor en ambos programas al que tienes en el convertidor de medios (MOXA) la ip configurada la tienes en: 10.10.10.100

reduce el resonse timeout en el modbus poll a 2000ms en lugar de 20.000ms.

adicional te recomiendo que vayas a la pagina de [www.modbus.org](http://www.modbus.org) y descargues la especificacion del protocolo modbus.

saludos
luis lopez

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).